# Conditional merging of two lists in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I am trying to combine two lists that complement each other, where one contains half the set of values and the second the other half:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,2,4) 
v2 <- c(NULL)
v3 <- c(1,2,2,4)
l1 <- list(v1,v2,v3)

v1b <- c(NULL) 
v2b <- c(1,2,2,4)
v3b <- c(NULL)
l2 <- list(v1b,v2b,v3b)

> l1
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
[[2]]
NULL
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 2 4

> l2
[[1]]
NULL
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
[[3]]
NULL
```

The desired result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
```

I tried several ways. This is the closest I got:

```
> sapply(l1, function(x) ifelse(x == "NULL", l2[[x]], x))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
[[2]]
logical(0)
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 2 4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Map('c', l1, l2)`

Comment: Great, that works. Just for learning, what does the 'c' mean?

Comment: @mace - it's referencing the function `c()` - used for `c`oncatenating objects together - `c(1,2,3)` for instance.